# When i run the BIP report error is occurring only interactive layout

Tags: oracle, report, interactive

When i am running the BIP report i am getting an error "Error occurred" only for interactive view , but when the change to HTML or excel it is running fine . Data model is running fine without any error . Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The same error happened to me. The issue was because f change in the Data model, path for some of the columns were different.

Edit the template, reassign the column values to the correct path.

should fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Interactive output is only available for layouts designed using BI Publisher's Layout Editor. Interactive output enables pop-up chart value displays, scrollable and filterable tables, and other interactive features for a report